# append PySpark dataframes (vertically) as in pandas.append()

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have one Dataframe ( or I could make it two datafarmes if necessary)

```
+---+-----------------+--------------------+
| id|    director_name|         movie_title|
+---+-----------------+--------------------+
| 01|    james cameron|              avatar|
| 02|   gore verbinski|pirates caribbean...|
| 03|       sam mendes|             spectre|
| 04|christopher nolan|   dark knight rises|
| 05|      doug walker|star wars episode...|
| 06|   andrew stanton|         john carter|
| 07|        sam raimi|        spider man 3|
| 08|     nathan greno|             tangled|
| 09|      joss whedon| avengers age ultron|
| 10|      david yates|harry potter half...|
+---+-----------------+--------------------+
```

I want it to look like this:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                 key|
+---+--------------------+
| 01|       james cameron|
| 02|      gore verbinski|
| 03|          sam mendes|
| 04|   christopher nolan|
| 05|         doug walker|
| 06|      andrew stanton|
| 07|           sam raimi|
| 08|        nathan greno|
| 09|         joss whedon|
| 10|         david yates|
| 01|              avatar|
| 02|pirates caribbean...|
| 03|             spectre|
| 04|   dark knight rises|
| 05|star wars episode...|
| 06|         john carter|
| 07|        spider man 3|
| 08|             tangled|
| 09| avengers age ultron|
| 10|harry potter half...|
+---+--------------------+
```

I surmise the Pandas method append() does this very same thing, but I could not find a solution for pySpark. I apologize if I have overlooked something!

I would like to avoid converting to pandas, as this df might get pretty big...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`stack`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#stack) function for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+----+----+
#| id|name|dept|
#+---+----+----+
#|  1|   a|   b|
#|  2|   c|   d|
#+---+----+----+

df.selectExpr("stack(2,string(id),name,string(id),dept)as (id,key)").show()
#+---+---+
#| id|key|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  a|
#|  1|  b|
#|  2|  c|
#|  2|  d|
#+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on an answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673403/how-to-stack-two-columns-into-a-single-one-in-pyspark), You can do the following:

```
director_name_df = df.select(['id', 'director_name']).('director_name', 'key')
movie_title_df = df.select(['id', 'movie_title']).withColumnRenamed('movie_title', 'key')
df = director_name_df .union(movie_title_df)
```

later you can drop duplicates if you want, Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the easiest ([How to stack two columns into a single one in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673403/how-to-stack-two-columns-into-a-single-one-in-pyspark)):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
movie_info = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     [1, 'James Cameron', 'Avatar'],
     [2, 'James Cameron', 'Titanic'],
     [3, "director_man", 'movie_2']
    ]
).toDF(*['id', 'director', 'movie'])

df = (
    movie_info
    .selectExpr('id', 'explode(array(director, movie))')
    .withColumnRenamed('col', 'key')
)

df.show()
```

but you could also do:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Create data
movie_info = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     [1, 'James Cameron', 'Avatar'],
     [2, 'James Cameron', 'Titanic'],
     [3, "director_man", 'movie_2']
    ]
).toDF(*['id', 'director', 'movie'])

# Only select id and director and change col to key
directors = (
    movie_info
    .select(
         'id',
         col('director').alias('key')
    )
)

# Only select id and movie and switch name to key
movies = (
    movie_info
    .select(
        'id',
        col('movie').alias('key')
    )
)


# Union together
unpivot = (
    directors
    .unionAll(movies)
)

unpivot.show()
```

```
+---+-------------+
| id|          key|
+---+-------------+
|  1|James Cameron|
|  2|James Cameron|
|  3| director_man|
|  1|       Avatar|
|  2|      Titanic|
|  3|      movie_2|
+---+-------------+
```